# Where should I ask questions about hardware?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Questions about hardware like:

1. If I put Visual Studio on an SSD, does it improve the speed of the software?
2. Which brand of SSD is better, Samsung or Kingston?

Answer (score 5):

Computer hardware questions belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). But …

> If I put Visual Studio on an SSD, does it improve the speed of the software?

How long is a piece of string? No, seriously, the answer will be, "yes" – if you compare it against a normal HDD – but you won't be able to quantify *how much faster* it'll be. There's no definitive answer to this question.

> Which brand of SSD is better, Samsung or Kingston?

This seems a little subjective.

You haven't defined what "good" means. Are you looking for reliability? Service and support? Compatibility? Price? Even then, shopping recommendations or simple polling questions like these are off topic for the entire Stack Exchange network.

You'd be better off comparing reviews. Or discussing this on our chat, if you want to get a few personal experiences and someone with an SSD of these brands is around.

Comment: _Seems_ a _little_ subjective? That looks like the picture-perfect subjective question to me.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda forgot to put the sarcasm tags around that.