# Question about PayPal support

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I've had a PayPal account associated with my main e-mail address for years, but I didn't create this account. For this reason I don't know the details like secret questions and stuff like that and I'm unable to reset my password and close my account because of that.

Communicating with PayPal's support has been unfruitful.

Is there a Stack Exchange site on which I could give a detailed description of what's happening and ask for help on how to close my account?

Comment: Not sure what you hope to achieve by such a site. For example, do you expect Paypal employees to be there as well? Stack Exchange did have a cooperation with Facebook for a while, but it was an utter failure. Doubt they'll do something similar again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Such a site? I never implied there would be a site exclusively dedicated for this. Perhaps my comment  [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245898/question-about-paypal-support#comment804735_245899) can shed some light on how I can be helped.

Comment: So the question better be changed to reflect this, now it focus on your very specific issue with Paypal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because my problem is with Paypal. I'm giving the amount of detail that I feel is right. I could remove the company's name, but I don't think that would help much.

Comment: If you want to ask purely about what laws exist to help you out, there is [this Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) which looks promising. Anyway, if you can't prove you own the account, I think it's kind of dead end.

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain to me how can I improve this question?

Comment: Here on MSE it means people disagree with the post, nothing you can really do about. Don't take it hard, I got -18 for [reporting a comma](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199097/that-comma-should-not-be-there).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Disagree with what? I didn't state anything, I asked a question. I'm aware of the voting behavior in meta sites, but I assumed this one was different since it attracts a lot of legitimate questions which aren't statements. Thanks.

Comment: In this case disagree in general about asking PayPal support questions anywhere on Stack Exchange. Site rec questions do get downvotes often, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158878/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-hardware also got -3.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not really any such site. Stack Exchange sites cannot offer such customer support, that is entirely a PayPal matter. Random users on the internet, however experienced, cannot handle account closures.

Also see [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) on Meta Stack Overflow.

That said, questions on how to *use* the PayPal website are [on topic for Web Apps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); they have a [`paypal` tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paypal) already.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not looking for customer support, I'm looking for a way to deal with a problem when the company's customer support refuses to help. For instance, someone might come up with a solution like sending an e-mail with a lawsuit threat to some @paypal.com address.

Comment: @GitGud: no site in the network can give this kind of support, no. If it is not about how to use the PayPal as a web application, it would be off-topic for Web Apps SE, and there are no other sites were questions in this direction would be suitable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment.